# How Use Sobel matrix with one pixel

Tags: android, image-processing

I wanna use `Sobel` operator in my android app. But I don't understand how use one pixel.

```
int sobel_x[][] = {{-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}};
int sobel_y[][] = {{-1, -2, -1},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 1}};
Bitmap source = ImageHelper.GetBitmapGromUri(Path);
    int w = source.getWidth();
    int h = source.getHeight();
    int[] pixels;
    pixels = new int[h * w];
    source.getPixels(pixels, 0, w, 1, 1, w - 1, h - 1);
    for(int i = 0;i < pixels.length;i++){
          ...
    }
```

I try use `get/setPixel`. But is very very slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news and bad news. The following works but...

Android, for some peculiar reason, doesn't allow you to create an 8 bit grey scale image. This means that you have to create a greyscale in ARGB_8888 format. This is probably what was going wrong in your previous version, we read data as bytes when it wasn't.

The code below works and I've only run it on an emulator against your image where it is *ridiculously* slow (11 seconds). Of course your image is very big but this is still, I would guess, way to slow.

I would strongly suggest considering using OpenCV Java libraries as they are both fast and memory efficient unlike the Android Bitmap class!

```
public class Sobel {
    private static Bitmap toGreyScale( Bitmap source ) {
        Bitmap greyScaleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(),
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        Canvas c = new Canvas(greyScaleBitmap);
        Paint p = new Paint();
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();

        cm.setSaturation(0);
        ColorMatrixColorFilter filter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
        p.setColorFilter(filter);
        c.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, p);
        return greyScaleBitmap;
    }

    public static void doSobel( Bitmap source) {

        Bitmap grey = toGreyScale(source);

        int w = grey.getWidth();
        int h = grey.getHeight();
        // Allocate 4 times as much data as is necessary because Android.
        int sz = w * h;

        IntBuffer buffer = IntBuffer.allocate( sz );
        grey.copyPixelsToBuffer( buffer );
        final int[] bitmapData = buffer.array();

        int[] output = new int[ w * h ];
        for( int y=1; y<h-1; y++ ) {
            for( int x=1; x<w-1; x++ ) {
                int idx = (y * w + x );

                // Apply Sobel filter
                int tl = (bitmapData[idx - w - 1]) & 0xFF;
                int tr = (bitmapData[idx - w + 1]) & 0xFF;
                int l = (bitmapData[idx - 1]) & 0xFF;
                int r = (bitmapData[idx + 1]) & 0xFF;
                int bl = (bitmapData[idx + w - 1]) & 0xFF;
                int br = (bitmapData[idx + w + 1]) & 0xFF;

                int sx = (int) ( tr - tl + 2 * ( r - l ) + br - bl );
                sx = sx & 0xFF;

                // Put back into ARG and B bytes
                output[toIdx] = (sx << 24) | ( sx << 16) | (sx << 8) | sx;
            }
        }

        source.copyPixelsFromBuffer( IntBuffer.wrap(output));
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep. Its work. In my phone - 0 sec.But `toIdx` == `idx`? and result no good :( [result](http://i59.tinypic.com/s6j42x.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Individual pixel access is definitely not the right way to go!

I assume that you have converted source to grayscale and so it's essentially a  byte array. I suggest you use something like the following to extract the data:

```
int w = source.getWidth();
int h = source.getHeight();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate( w * h );
source.copyPixelsToBuffer( buffer );
final byte[] bitmapData = buffer.array()
```

This gives you the source data. You can now apply your Sobel filters to it. Note that you want to write the resulting output bytes into a new `byte` array and then convert that back into an image.

```
byte[] output = new byte[ w * h ];
for( int y=1; y<h-1; y++ ) {
    for( int x=1; x<w-1; x++ ) {
        int idx = y * w + x;

        // Apply Sobel filter
        byte sx = (byte) ((-1 * bitmapData[idx-w-1]) + ( 1 * bitmapData[idx-w+1] ) + (-2 * bitmapData[idx-1]) + ( 2 * bitmapData[idx+1] ) + (-1 * bitmapData[idx+w-1]) + ( 1 * bitmapData[idx+w+1] ) );

        output[idx] = sx;
    }
}
```

You can so similarly for the horizontal filter.

**Edited** to correct type of output from int to byte

Comment: `int[] output = new byte[ w * h ];` - error. if use int array. how set to result? `result.setPixels(output,0,w,0,0,w,h);`???  if byte array - `result.copyPixelsFromBuffer( output );`  ??

Comment: @NickDevil  make output an int[] and use `Bitmap.createBitmap (int[] colors, int offset, int stride, int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config)` or similar. Or make output a byte[] and use `copyPixelsFromBuffer()`

Comment: its work, but result its not good... [result](http://i61.tinypic.com/10ogqad.jpg) and [source](http://i58.tinypic.com/i3gg0i.png)

Comment: @NickDevil You need to make sure that the Bitmap type is the same as the source data you use. i.e. set config, stride, offset etc. appropriately for the data type that you're using.

Comment: Bitmap res = Bitmap.createBitmap(output,0,w,w,h,source.getConfig()); - i use this.

Comment: i try  `ByteBuffer bufferOut = ByteBuffer.wrap(output);
        result.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bufferOut);` but `result.copyPixelsFromBuffer(bufferOut);` - no work

Comment: Sobel matrix is fine. Make sure input image is greyscale, (byte, not float) and that the output Bitmap is created the same. Your latest results, the output bitmap is colour, it must be 8 bit greyscale.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77287/discussion-between-nickdevil-and-dave-durbin).